# How to access a variable in the template inside its' respective controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create some sort of search functionality in Ember and I have having some trouble passing the input field's value to the controller to process.

This is what I have

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        handle_search: function() {
            var search_text = this.get('controllers.search_text');
            console.log(search_text);
        }
    }
});
```

and this is what I have in the template

```
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                {{input type="text" valueBinding=search_text class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."}}

                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button {{action 'handle_search'}} class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
                </span>
```

This gives me the following error

```
WARNING: You're attempting to render a view by passing valueBinding=search_text to a view helper, but this syntax is ambiguous. You should either surround search_text in quotes or remove `Binding` from valueBinding. ember.js:3521

Error Uncaught object
```

So I also tried `value` instead of `valueBinding` and `this.controller.get('search_text') instead of`this.get('controllers.search_text');` and I get this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined app.js:127`

So how do I access values in the controller that are set in the template? The `search_text` variable is just some name I created in the template so I can try accessing the input's value on the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties exist right on the controller, so you can use `this.get('foo')`

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        handle_search: function() {
            var search_text = this.get('search_text');
            console.log(search_text);
        }
    }
});
```

And valueBinding should only be used when you are binding to a property using a textual version of its name, e.g. `valueBinding='foo'`.  If you want to bind directly to a property you just do `value=foo`.

```
 {{input type="text" value=search_text class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/weyobivu/1/edit